# ccache-swig : wrong size and over limit

Tags: ccache

We use ccache-swig on small server used  for CI compilations.

Stats reports that everything is ok.

```
]$ ccache-swig -s
cache directory                     PATH/.ccache
cache hit                          18345
cache miss                         17097
compile failed                         5
preprocessor error                    11
unsupported compiler option        21039
files in cache                      2256
cache size                         757.3 Mbytes
max cache size                     976.6 Mbytes
```

But in reality

```
]$ du -hs .ccache/
1.7G    .ccache/
```

Launching

```
ccache-swig -c
```

will solve the situation. But only for a little time. Some days later .ccache size will bypass the limit and stats will be wrong.
Leaving this situation for a long period lead to have .ccache really big.

I'm not very familiar nor with ccache, not with compilation details. But this situation seems a little bit strange for me.

According to man the size should be fixed automatically :

When these limits are reached ccache will reduce the cache to 20% below the numbers you specified in order to avoid doing the cache clean operation too often.

So the questions :

1. Is it normal (i.e. is it known issue? Is it normal behavior? )
2. What could we do ? Launching "ccache-swig -c" regulary using cron ? It seems ugly for me (but well... it's still a solution).

**Small Update** :
I forgot to give some information.

```
]$ ccache-swig -V
ccache-swig version 4.1.0
Copyright Andrew Tridgell 2002
Released under the GNU GPL v2 or later
```

And we are on RockyLinux9 (but this behavior was observed also on CentOS 7 servers).